# Matplotlib.pyplot module not being found in vscode

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble importing matplotlib.pyplot using vscode, I am getting ModuleNotFound. I have installed the package using anaconda, I can run the same code in Jupiter notebook with no problems. What is the issue?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The python file on the left of your screenshot is called `matplotlib.py` Try renaming that to something else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, that didn't solve the issue however the error is now different, now it says: ImportError: cannot import name 'pyplot' from 'matplotlib' (/Users/josephshenouda/Desktop/matplotlib.py)

Comment: Obviously you made a classic mistake, the file name conflicts with the package name that needs to be imported.Please rename your script file